# UICollectionView reloadData works, but reloadItemsAtindexPaths not

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I experimenting with pretty simple thing: add image on `UICollectionViewCell's` imageView on button pressed. (actually, `CollectionViewCell` - is custom cell with `UIImageView` `IBOutlet`)

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.cell=cell;
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)actionAddImage:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    UIImage* image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
   self.cell.imageView.image=image;
   NSIndexPath* path= [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:self.cell];
   [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[path]];
}
```

There is only one cell. And on first button press nothing happens, on second - image appear. I put `NSLog`, and revealed, that

```
CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

return new cell instead of existing. Though `indexPath` is strongly (section=0, row=0),i.e. there is only one cell.
However, `reloadData` works perfectly, but without animation of course.

```
- (IBAction)actionAddImage:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    UIImage* image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
   self.cell.imageView.image=image;
   [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_array =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@{@"option":[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]},@{@"option":[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]},@{@"option":[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]},@{@"option":[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]}, nil];

- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    questionImageCollectionViewCell * cell=[self.questionCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"coustomCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.optionImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[_optionImageArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];


    NSDictionary *dic = self.array[indexPath.row];

    if ([dic[@"option"] boolValue]) {
        [cell.rightTickImg setHidden:NO];
    }else{
      [cell.rightTickImg setHidden:YES];

    }
   // [cell.rightTickImg setHidden:YES];
    return cell;


}


- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        //[self.array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDictionary *dic = @{@"option":[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]};
    [self.array insertObject:dic atIndex:indexPath.row];

    [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];

}
```

Comment: use this code hide and Display imageview on collection view cell

Answer (score 0):

First time, your code is very insecure. You should not assign your reusable cell when you "create it" in 'collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:' instead of you can to try to do it:

```
- (IBAction)actionAddImage:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender 
{
    NSIndexPath *path    = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]; // i suppose you can reload cell at section 0 position 0
    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:path];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];

    cell.imageView.image = image;

    .... reload _collectionView at Path 'path' ....
}
```

Between other things this external reference you do to the reusable cell not is immutable in time.

Comment: I understood you. I used your code, but nothing has changed. `reloadData` work, `[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[path]];`- not work. When the last one used, in method - `(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];` cell is different. Maybe it is bag?

Comment: Not, of this way the cells would be the same and you only have one so must be ever the same. Please debug your code cell and put a break point inside 'actionAddImage:' before you assign 'image' to the cell and explore cell object and tell me if attribute 'imageView' of the cell is nil or is initialized ;)

Comment: imageView is initialized..
`UIImage* image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"];
    NSLog(@"before reload %@",cell.imageView);
    cell.imageView.image=image;`
`before reload <UIImageView: 0x7fbce9c70b90; frame = (15 6; 24 116); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbce9c6efc0>>`